# Nature of expansion of an ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Consider an ideal gas expanding irreversibly in a piston-cylinder system against a lower external pressure. According to this graph, does the piston move such that the internal pressure changes with respect to Boyle's Law (i.e. along the dotted line)? Or does it change linearly with volume (i.e. along the solid line)?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

What are you representing on the axes? $P$ and $V$? If so, the solid lines don't represent a linear change of pressure with volume, but first an isochoric ($V$ = const) and then a isobaric transformation ($P$ = const).

Anyway, the transformation really depends on the motion of the piston, and its speed, and the heat transfer through the walls of the system: "fast" expansion may be approximated with an adiabatic transformation, "slow" expansion with conductive wall may be approximated with a isothermic transformation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your two questions is neither. That’s because the gas pressure (and temperature) is undefined during the irreversible process, except at the initial and final equilibrium states 1 and 2. In between those states the gas is not in equilibrium with the surrounding. Internally, pressure and temperature gradients exist.

The pressure shown on the PV diagram is always the external pressure. The gas pressure only equals the external pressure for a reversible process. For an irreversible process it equals the external pressure only at the interface in the case of a massless frictionless piston. However, unless the process is described as irreversible, we generally assume the pressure on the diagram is both the gas equilibrium pressure and the pressure of the surroundings.

Since you mentioned Boyle’s law in connection with the dotted line it would represent a reversible isothermal expansion where $PV=$ constant which takes place in a constant temperature surroundings. The external pressure is slowly reduced so that the gas temperature and pressure is always in equilibrium with the surroundings so that for the gas $PV=nRT$ at each point in the process.

For the irreversible path the gas is initially in pressure and temperature equilibrium with the surroundings when the external pressure is suddenly reduced. (Visualize a vertically oriented piston/cylinder with a weight initially on top being suddenly removed, leaving only atmospheric pressure).The gas then rapidly expands at constant external pressure until it eventually comes back into equilibrium with the surroundings at point 2.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If the piston is massless and frictionless, then, from Newton's 2nd law of motion, the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the inside face of the piston is equal to the external pressure on the outside face of the piston (at all times).  However, from fluid dynamics, you will learn that, for an irreversible expansion or compression, the force per unit area exerted by the gas on the inside face of the piston includes both the pressure determined by the ideal gas law (or other real gas equation of state) plus viscous forces caused by rapid deformation of the gas.  The latter result from the 3D version of Newton's law of viscosity.  Without a detailed fluid mechanics analysis using the partial differential equations of fluid dynamics, these cannot be elucidated.  So, for an irreversible expansion of compression, in practical terms, the work can only be easily obtained if the force on the external face of the piston is controlled or specified.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state inside the piston is held at $p_i, V_i$. The external pressure is reduced to $p_x < p_i$ and the piston is released. The piston undergoes a constant pressure expansion. The process is irreversible. We cannot predict how internal pressure changes with piston volume for an irreversible process. We can only establish the final state. To do so, we would need to know whether piston walls are perfectly insulated or diathermal so that we can carry out a hypothetical adiabatic or isothermal path to predict the final state.